# Network bus with tree topology with network exploration

Tags: digital-communications, bus, network

I am planing to experiment with Arduino framework to create a network of microcontrollers, where they communicate with each other. There will be one master and this should be able to explore the network to create a map. I suppose that this is a tree topology.
In the picture below, the red node is the master, which talks to blues first (each line is serial interface) and asks, if they have children. They then ask their children the same question. Each node passes the subtopology to the top until the master receives an answer from each child. After this discovery phase, master knows how to reach each member in the network. Members may or may not talk to each other (I am not if I need this in the future).

[image: tree topology]

I was wondering, which technologies are there on the software and hardware level? I did my homework and found out that many known network busses work out, if my microcontrollers have two separate hardware implementations. e.g. 2xSPI or 2xI2C or 2xUART.

I wonder, if there is a commonly used bus for such applications? I was thinking of reading and passing on the packets based on the content to the next node. But that might be an overkill for the microcontrollers. Maybe there are more suitable solutions out there? e.g. even CAN bus seems to support tree topology. For instance, if the number of direct children is more than 2, then a set of CAN busses seem to be more suitable. Since, I am doing this for the first time, I am not sure, if I am looking in the right direction.

Edit: thanks to the comments, I have a few more things to consider. But cover the questions:

***Why one-to-one link?***

The nodes will be part of an attachable layout. My thought was that on a bus, devices can't figure out the topology. If 5 devices sit in a chain, how can the red node figure out that yellow comes after blue? But if blue must pass yellow's package to the red, then it can figure out own topology and pass it on to red.

***Data rates***

I am ok with anything 10000 or above kbit/s.

***CAN***

I can see CAN to be useful there are multiple direct children, but can it work to figure out the topology? It is crucial that the red node can realize the structure. (Which nodes are direct children, which are their children etc.)

To my knowledge if they sit on the same bus, then it is not possible.

Some commonly used (hobbyist) microcontrollers come at least with 2 sets of UART pins (hardware). If I go down that approach I can create at least a binary tree. But I think that I am missing something more practical and efficient, which is a common industry standard for similar applications.

I think that my limitation is an overview and proper terminology to continue my research on existing solutions, before reinventing the wheel.

Comment: What are your constraints, and why have you settled on the one-to-one link topology outlined here? For example, RS485 and CAN would trivially allow all nodes to sit on the same link / bus, without the BOM cost of transceivers for each port and associated software stacks... i.e: 8x (one each) vs 14x (some with _four!_) line drivers, and thus supporting peripherals (which may be difficult to achieve)

Comment: If you're doing it all from scratch, then you get to decide.

Comment: the blue one on the left has 4 connections,  maybe you can use an external or internal  multiplexer  to switch one transceiver across the 4 different ports, but it gets simpler if you have 4 transceivers.

Comment: Which bus to use?  well that depends on the data rate you need and how long the wires are.

Comment: VPNer, There is not a one-size-fits-all-situations that could ever become the *"commonly used bus"* for everything possessing the topology you show. It's too generalized and for any realized bus, details will matter. And, as always, engineering choices will be made to balance cost and performance and other factors. How could there be some single solution that trumps all the others with only some very general statement made like this? Set enough boundaries and maybe some answer could arrive. But not with so little given. It's a pretty picture. That's all.

Comment: I tried to answer the questions and put more context.